# Android - Tab and mobile compatible codes (supported screens

Tags: android, mobile, tabs, screen

i have an android web app .. i tried to add some those codes to make it compatible  with tabs which happened but now it is not compatible with mobiles

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" />


<compatible-screens>
    <!--no small size screens -->


    <!--all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <!-- all large size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <!-- all xlarge size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <!-- Special case for Nexus 7 -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="213" />

</compatible-screens>

<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" />
<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="480" />
<screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="480" />
```

which code should i keep and which one to remove

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current phones should be xxxhdpi, so you must add 2 lines for each screensize having `android:screenDensity` set to xxhdpi and xxxhdpi like this

...